# Removing exact duplicate rows from presto

Tags: sql, presto, trino

With the following table (assuming it has many other rows and columns), how could I query it while removing duplicates?

| order_id | customer_name | amount | bill_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Chris | 10 | sale |
| 1 | Chris | 1 | tip |
| 1 | Chris | 10 | sale |

Note that while all 3 rows are about the same order, only row 3 is a duplicate -- since row 2 tells us about the tips of that order.

Using `distinct order_id` would remove rows 2 and 3, while I am looking to **only remove row 3.**

Appreciate any ideas

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want a new result set, you can use:

```
select distinct t.*
from t;
```

I would suggest saving this into a new table, if you need to materialize the result.